# How to change the Navigation bar default back button

Tags: ios, swift

Hi there I'm not able to change the navigation bar default back button's title

I've tried that :

```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title="retour"
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title="retour"
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title="retour"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title="retour"
```

Answer (score 2):

Set as `leftBarButtonItem`

```
var backBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "retour", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
```

Comment: Thanks it has changed the title, but when I press the back button I got an error  `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa451440910`

Comment: Try changing `action=nil`

Comment: Nothings happens when I click on the back button

Comment: Try `self.navigationItem.title = "retour"`

Comment: it works fine with the title but no with the back button

Comment: `self.navigationItem.title = "retour"` will change only title. So default action will not be affected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85277/discussion-between-frequencymatched-and-yasser-b).